# After running ionic serve facing error: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

After running ionic serve facing error: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. I have reinstall ionic, cordova and node.js but still faceing this error

```
C:\Users\ali\Documents\TransporterApp>ionic serve
    [INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --address 0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to
           cancel
    [21:24:00]  watch started ...
    [21:24:00]  build dev started ...
    [21:24:00]  clean started ...
    [21:24:00]  clean finished in 3 ms
    [21:24:00]  copy started ...
    [21:24:00]  transpile started ...
    [21:24:07]  typescript: ...ts/TransporterApp/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/vinyl_file.d.ts, line: 1 
                Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
```

L1:  export interface VinylFile extends Object {

L2:      path: string;

```
    [21:24:07]  typescript: ...ts/TransporterApp/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/vinyl_file.d.ts, line: 11 
                Cannot find name 'Buffer'.


    [21:24:07]  typescript: ...D2D-Transporter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/clean-css-factory.d.ts, line: 2 
                Namespace ''*'' has no exported member 'Options'.
```

L1:  import * as cleanCss from 'clean-css';

L2:  export declare function getCleanCssInstance(options: cleanCss.Options): cleanCss;

L3:  export interface CleanCssConfig {

```
    [21:24:07]  typescript: ...D2D-Transporter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/clean-css-factory.d.ts, line: 2 
                Cannot find name 'cleanCss'.
```

L1:  import * as cleanCss from 'clean-css';

L2:  export declare function getCleanCssInstance(options: cleanCss.Options): cleanCss;

L3:  export interface CleanCssConfig {

```
    [21:24:07]  typescript: ...D2D-Transporter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/clean-css-factory.d.ts, line: 6 
                Namespace ''*'' has no exported member 'Options'.
```

L5:      destFileName: string;

L6:      options?: cleanCss.Options;

```
    [21:24:07]  typescript: ...2D-Transporter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/virtual-file-utils.d.ts, line: 1 
                Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

       L1:  import { Stats } from 'fs';   
       L2:  export declare class VirtualStats implements Stats {


    [21:24:07]  typescript: ...2D-Transporter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/virtual-file-utils.d.ts, line: 3 
                Cannot find name 'Stats'.

       L2:  export declare class VirtualStats implements Stats {

       L3:      protected _path: string;     

       L4:      protected _ctime: Date;

    [21:24:07]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/ 

    [INFO] Development server running
           Local: http://localhost:8100

    [21:24:07]  copy finished in 6.75 s
    [21:24:07]  watch ready in 6.97 s
```

> ```
> System info are:
>
> cli packages:
>
>     @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.0 (C:\Users\ali\Documents\TransporterApp\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-ionic-angular)
>     @ionic/cli-utils                : 1.6.0 (C:\Users\ali\Documents\TransporterApp\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils)
>     ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.6.0 (C:\Users\ali\Documents\TransporterApp\node_modules\ionic)
>
> global packages:
>
>     Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
>
> local packages:
>
>     @ionic/app-scripts        : 1.3.7
>     @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.4.1
>     Cordova Platforms         : none
>     Ionic Framework           : ionic-angular 3.2.1
>
> System:
>
>     Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
>     Node              : v6.11.1
>     OS                : Windows 7
>     npm               : 3.10.10
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered to this issue before:

> npm install @types/node --save-dev

worked for me.